# C# Is there a way to create functions that accept anonymous function code as argument?

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like

```
NameOfTheMethod(parameters){
  // Code...
}
```

There's using, foreach, for, etc. that are already built-in, but I don't know if creating something similar is even possible. Is it?

The reason why I ask this is because sometimes that there are many different pieces of code that are wrapped by basically the same code (examples are opening a connection to the database, creating the command, settings the datareader, testing if an element exists in cache and, if not, go get it, otherwise get it from cache, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can take a delegate instance as an argument:

```
void MyMethod(Func<Arg1Type, Arg2Type, ReturnType> worker) {
    Arg1Type val1 = something;
    Arg2Type val2 = somethingelse;
    ReturnType retVal = worker(something, somethingelse);
    // ...
}
```

You'd call it like:

```
MyMethod((arg1, arg2) => {
  // do something here with the arguments
  return result;
});
```

Comment: Great, @Mehrdad! Can you please provide a link where I can learn more about this. Probably I am not searching well enough. Thanks!

Comment: C# has way to pass arount type-safe pointers to functions via Delegates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80).aspx
Func and Action are both specific type of delegates created for easier passing of function pointers around.